# Website down after Jetpack connect to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

I uploaded my wordpress site on free hosting site. It started off well but had some problems. It had jetpack installed in it and its portfolio link was not appearing. On the page of the installed plugins list, It asked to connect to wordpress.com. I clicked it, It hung for some seconds than I closed it. Since then my site is not working at all. No response is coming from server. Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Go to the plugins directory on your server, find jetpack, and change the permissions to 0000.

Comment: I changed to 000 but it changes to 0700. And didn't work. My site is hosted at 000webhost.com. Is it possible that its hosting or domain problem? Maybe blocked or something?

Comment: yes. you cannot use web sockets over anything but port 80 on 000webhost.com's free hosting service.

Comment: please explain me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate Jetpack plugin and reinstall Jetpack plugin on your website. But first, you need to create a complete backup on your website.

If you want to guide about Jetpack plugin kindly see the link below:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/integrate-jetpack-wordpress-plugin/